# Как правильно создать базу данных mysql для товаров с разными свойствами и категориями

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, json, filter

Помогите как правильно организовать структуру БД интернет магазина где у товаров есть разные свойства и категории. Чтобы было легче для фильтрации и производительность не снизился. 
Погуглил и нашел два способа: **отдельная таблица с свойствами товаров** (id товара - свойство - значение)  и **поля типа JSON** с свойствами товаров. Но что из них лучше. Или есть другие варианты. Поделитесь опытом, дайте совет.

Comment: Разделяй всё. 3 - таблицы 1) Категории 2) свойства 3) Товары. Товары привязываются к категориям. Свойства привязываются к товарам.
Таким образом выбирая категорию и свойство ты получаешь товары ну разумеется товары индексируются по категориям, свойства по товарам

Comment: EAV - это боль. Поэтому да, для свойств - индексируемый JSON. Но только надо помнить, что в noSQL базах контроль за целостностью лежит на пользователях. Поэтому должна быть очень жесткая спецификация на структуру JSON. А категории - банальная связь многие ко многим

Comment: как выполнить фильтрацию товаров, если свойства хранятся в JSON. Легко ли реализовать. И как с производительностью.

Comment: @ErkulanBarmaganbetov, последние версии баз данных поддерживают поиск по JSON полю. Не знаю насчёт производительности, но тот же EAV не сахар и приходится использовать какой-нибудь solr.